# How to use a math expression in default values?

Tags: php, math

Why doesn't the following work in PHP?

> const DAYS = 60*24*3;

I get the following error.

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONST on line 1

I'm also not able to assign an expression to the value of a property array. Note, I'm only using constant values (not calling functions or anything like that).

```
class A
{
    public $value = array('days'=>60*24*3);
}
```

The above doesn't work.

> $value = array('days'=>60*24*3);

**But that works fine if it's assigned to a local variable!**

How do you use math expressions when assigning values?

Comment: did you defined the constant? define(CONSTANT, 'value')?

Comment: oh, that's a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Constants are defined using the `define()` function. `const` is a reserved word inside classes (and is not possible to be used outside the class scope until PHP 5.3). Therefore:

```
define('DAYS', 60*24*3);
```

will work fine.

Comment: True, but this makes it a global constant. That's not the same thing as just saying `public $property = 10+2-3;`

Answer (score 0):

While defining a constant works fine, it changes the global scope. A more encapsulated way of doing this would be by setting the property in the constructor:

```
<?php

class Foo {

    private $duration;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->duration = 60 * 60 * 24 * 3;
    }
}
```